# Movie ID: Alien lifeform runs rampant on ISS

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this sci-fi movie a while ago. Anyways, the movie wasn't made more than 4 years ago, and it is about this single-cell alien lifeform that is found on Mars. It is sent to the ISS to be studied. The lifeform evolves very quickly and is intelligent. It quickly grows to a pretty big size and becomes hostile to the astronauts on the ISS.

At some point, NASA sends up a Soyuz capsule to push the ISS out of its Earth orbit to try and save the world from this thing. I can't remember if it does anything, but by then, the last two living astronauts decide that they have to do something.

They each board Soyuz capsules that are there to be lifeboats in case of an 'abandon ship' scenario. One of the astronauts decides to be a distraction to get the alien on board so that the capsule will take them both away from the Earth to a slow death. The other one tries to get back to Earth.

You'd think that the distraction guy would succeed, even with the alien inside the capsule with the astronaut, trying to get him to let go of the manual controls so that autopilot wouldn't kick in and pilot the capsule to Earth, but he fails. And of course, the other astronaut's autopilot fails and suffers a slow but inevitable demise in space. Sadly, the alien gets to Earth and probably destroys the world.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This would likely be *[Life](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5442430/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, released just last year in 2017.

From the IMDB description:

> A team of scientists aboard the International Space Station discover a rapidly evolving life form that caused extinction on Mars and now threatens all life on Earth.

Comment: If this doesn't match other details, let me know; again, didn't actually see this one myself.

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much. Also, as I said, I do have a bad memory for titles, so I apologize if that is inconvenient.